# Boolean Expression Evaluation

Tags: expression

I have a string (R(46 - 9900)) AND ( NOT (R(48 - 9900))) where R denotes Range . If you evaluate the expression it results in R(46-47) , considering the logical operators (AND,NOT).

I have a requirement where I need to parse such a string and evaluate it to a correct result . I have to use C++ as a programming tool to achieve this result .

Can anyone suggest a few guide lines as to how do I proceed on this ?

Comment: Exact duplicate (same user, yesterday): [Parsing Range Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003514/parsing-range-expressions)

Comment: @Paul The sole intention was to publish it under a correct tag

Comment: in that case you just need to edit the tags on the original question - you don't need to start all over again and duplicate the question just to change the tags. Also, you already had a perfectly good answer to the first question, which you failed to acknowledge (and I see you have now deleted this - why ?).

Comment: That’s not a boolean expression, it’s a set expression even though you used `and` and `not` instead of the typical set arithmetic notation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reposting `Aftershock`'s answer to your question the first time you posted it, since it was a good answer and it didn't deserve to be deleted:

---

You have to write a small interpreter. There are many ways to do it . Here is one. Here is pattern for it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern

This can help too: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/08/19/966.aspx That is about the intersection of data ranges but the problem is similar.

You may also use an operator precedense parser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser

---